# [Generic Connectivity Using ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (SQL State: 07001; SQL Code: 0)

Tags: sql-server, oracle

> *ERROR at line 1:
>
>   ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle
>   system returned this message:
>
>   [Generic Connectivity Using
>   ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
>
>   COUNT field incorrect or syntax error
>
>   (SQL State: 07001; SQL Code: 0) ORA-06512: at line 9*

Anyone know this error.. pls help us.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you **at least** show the query that caused this error? What's the setup? There's SQL Server and Oracle involved - how are those connected?? You need to put a **bit more effort** into your question!

Comment: You'll need to show us line 1 (i.e. the code that generated the error) in order for us to help. Have you tried running the pass through query directly on SQL Server?

Comment: @user1802125 you really need to put your SQL in the comment in the answer below in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Since you do not provide any type of code from where this error is generated I can only guess here. After asking Google and found [this](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/error-sqlstates/), it looks like `COUNT field incorrect or syntax error` could mean that you use the wrong number of parameters in your call.

If you posted the code where the error is generated from it could help a lot to understand what could go wrong.

Comment: declare
  c INTEGER;
 nr integer;
  v_jv VARCHAR2(20);
 begin
 c := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@SQLDB;
 DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@SQLDB(c,'begin; getLocation &?; end;');
 DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.BIND_OUT_VARIABLE@SQLDB(c, 1, v_jv);
 nr := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_NON_QUERY@SQLDB(c);
 DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.GET_VALUE@SQLDB(c, 1, v_jv);
 DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@SQLDB(c);
 --commit;
 dbms_output.put_line('v_PLACE='||v_jv);
 end;

Comment: here getLocation are SQL Server Stored procedure its return only one out parameter.. we solved one and more IN parameter is successfully using  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE.

Comment: Does this mean you solved your issue with EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE? In your PARSE call above, don't you have to use exec to call the procedure? I don't have access to a MSSQL server to test this.

Answer (score 1):

I just lost at least an hour+ debugging my code to see what the issue was. I was using an ADODB connection in VBA with parameters. Apparently if don't have the `Set` keyword, debugging output will look like the parameter has a value, but it's not actually there upstream. Of course I knew `Set` was needed, but it's easy to overlook when you're trying to spot the problem.

Problem:

```
    params(1) = cmd.CreateParameter("Email_ID", adInteger, adParamInput, , EmailID)
```

Corrected code:

```
    Set params(1) = cmd.CreateParameter("Email_ID", adInteger, adParamInput, , EmailID)
```